# function as function input php

Tags: php, function

I want to create my own template for building my next web projects.

But my problem is that I am trying to create my own template system with my own function, also to learn more about coding on my on aswell.

I'm trying to improve my code to be me clean/smooth as I code.

But now I ran into this problem

**a-function-file.php**

```
<?php    
$Website_info = array("SiteTitle"=>"CLiCK", "BaseUrl"=>"http://localhost/CLick/");

//css styles her
$website_styles = array(
array("src"=>"libs/css/bootstrap.min.css", "type"=>"text/css"),
array("src"=>"libs/themes/click.css", "type"=>"text/css")
);

//javascripts her
$website_scripts = array(
array("src"=>"libs/js/bootstrap.min.js", "type"=>"text/javascript")
);


$website_navigation_top_links = array(
array("link"=>"index.php","name"=>"Home")
);


function Click_styles()
{
    global $website_styles;
    $styleOutput = "";
    foreach ($website_styles as $key => $CssStyle):
    $styleOutput .=  "<link href='".$CssStyle["src"]."' rel='stylesheet' type='".$CssStyle["type"]."'>\n";
    endforeach;
    return $styleOutput;
}

//my function to create html codes within head tags
function Click_header() 
{
    //Getting website info into function
    global $Website_info;
    global $website_styles;
    $ImpotedStyles = Click_styles();    
    //creating the html (can maybe be created more clean later)
    $Header_output = "<title>".$Website_info["SiteTitle"]."</title>\n";
    $Header_output .= "<base href='".$Website_info["BaseUrl"]."' />\n";
    $Header_output = $Header_output.$ImpotedStyles;
    // return the complied output (as HTML)
    return $Header_output;
}

?>
```

So far so good, because this works if I write

```
<?php echo Click_header();?>
```

But I want to use the function like this with, by passing it a function as an argument

```
<?php 
//the function that doesnt work
function printHTML($ThisShouldBeAFunctionNotAVar, $Description="none") {
    echo $ThisShouldBeAFunctionNotAVar
}
?>


<?php
//how I want to use the function
printHTML(Click_header(), "The website header");
//and maybe if I had a footer I could display the return of that function too
printHTML(Click_foter(), "a smart footer function");
?>
```

I hope you can help me with this or get a better understanding for maybe something smarter

Comment: I fount this solution on my own
`code`
<?php
function printHTML($CustomFunction,$Description="")
{
 $function = ($CustomFunction;
    echo $function();
}
?>
`code`

Answer (score 0):

I fount this solution on my own

```
<?php
function printHTML($CustomFunction,$Description="")
{
 $function = ($CustomFunction;
    echo $function();
}
?>
```